# What is Data Locality in Apache Spark?

Tags: pyspark

I am newbie to apache-spark

I have a hard time understanding Data Locality in Apache Spark. I have tried to read this article https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-performance-tuning/
which says "PROCESS_LOCAL"  and "NODE_LOCAL". Are there settings I need to configure?
Can someone take an example and explain it to me?

Thanks,
Padd

Answer (score 3):

Data locality in simple terms means doing computation on the node where data resides.

Just to elaborate:

Spark is cluster computing system. It is not a storage system like HDFS or NOSQL. Spark is used to process the data stored in such distributed system.

Typical installation is like spark is installed on same nodes as that of HDFS/NOSQL.

In case there is a spark application which is processing data stored HDFS. Spark tries to place computation tasks alongside HDFS blocks.

With HDFS the Spark driver contacts NameNode about the DataNodes (ideally local) containing the various blocks of a file or directory as well as their locations (represented as InputSplits), and then schedules the work to the SparkWorkers.

Note : Spark’s compute nodes / workers should be running on storage nodes.

This is how data locality achieved in Spark.

The advantage is performance gain as less data is transferred over the network.

Try the below articles for reading - There are n number of documents availavle in google to search for
http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/09/01/Spark-Locality/
https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/performance_optimization/data_locality.html